# Why Add Image from the web shows error always?

Tags: discussion, support

Whenever i try to **upload image From the web** option it shows error, not able to upload, see the below screenshot. So i need to download the image from website and then upload through **From my computer** option. I think this feature have problem uploading images.

It shows the message **Failed to upload image, the format is not supported**, but tried most common format jpg, png no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading: What happens is that imgur.com is not able to download the picture.
That is what happens with Drupal.org, for example. See [Does the image upload have more restrictive requirements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184869/does-the-image-upload-have-more-restrictive-requirements)

Comment: if it other than drupal.org, will it work ?

Comment: It will happen with every server that blocks its images from being served from other sites.